# Spaces on directories using "cd" Unix command

Tags: unix, syntax

I've been trying to access a directory but it seems as if I'm not allowed to do an indirect cd command. I'm trying to access

```
> C:\Program Files
```

But it seems like using `cd \Program Files` doesn't work, I also tried `cd \Program_Files` but to no avail, what is the correct syntax?

Comment: Try `cd "C:\\Program Files"`. The backward slash is an escape character in Unix so you have to escape to mean a literal backward slash

Comment: I indeed used the backward slash, but found that I had to put it after "Program" like this `C:\Program\ Files`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape with '\'

```
cd C:\Program\ Files
```

Comment: The other option is to put quotes around the path:
`cd "C:\Program Files"`